# How to make The Flutter Application online

Tags: flutter

i have question when someone finish his flutter app with nodjs backend how can i make the application online like when u store queries in DB every body can reach the DB
like firebase but other platforms

Comment: https://www.docker.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking how to set up a backend. You can use a server from cloud providers like *google cloud platform /AWS /Oracle cloud* or you can use a hosting provider like *hostinger*. Then you can upload your backend (Nodejs) code there.
If you plan to use a cloud prvider like GCP, AWS, Oracle cloud there are free compute machines awailable for startups. At first there is a bit setup to do, which you can easily do by waching a youtube tutorial.